# Look of an Alert Dialog

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

Why my alert dialog does not look like a window as

Expected: [image: expected alert dialog] but what I get is

Actual:[image: actual alert dailog].

How to get the expected alert dailog??

Comment: look up material design, you need to opt into some things...

Comment: Thank you guys thanks for your responses, I have changed the style of the alert dialog using ContextThemeWrapper class.

Answer (score 0):

You will be need custom design for your desire. Use this way

```
  @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
private void emailDialog() {

    AlertDialog.Builder dialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
    View dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog, null);
    dialogBuilder.setView(dialogView);
    AlertDialog alertDialog = dialogBuilder.create();

    TextView textView = (TextView) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.textView);
    TextView textView2 = (TextView) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    textView.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.dialog_header_background_blue));
    alertDialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));

    textView.setText("EMAIL SENT");
    textView2.setText("Link has been sent to your Email");
    alertDialog.show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can change the look of alert dialogs, just leave it the way as it is now.

I think the looks of alert dialogs vary from theme to theme.
Try changing your activity's theme to maybe Holo and it may look different! And you can keep changing it until you find what you want.